FieldPanel isDirty() not working as expected
Fieldpanel is giving isDirty()=true even though i am not changing any field and also calling ResetOriginalValue() on each field as i have similar requirement  please check , the below fiddle for more ,
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3r6a
The combobox seems the culprit here , as without calling resetOriginalValue() to combo it is working fine.
also if i select any item from combo and then calling resetOriginalValue() it is working fine.
But if i don't change anything in the field panel and then checking isDirty then its not working.
please help me out !
If i use any other field than combobox then its working as expected , i am expecting then it should work as expected with combobox as well

Please change the following:

Ext.form.Panel instead of Ext.field.Panel

Add to the combobox value: ''

Use the following lines to reset your form:
var fPanel = this.up('formpanel');
fPanel.reset();




Thanks for looking into it...your way seems better.. when we add value='' its working fine with existing code as well. but the main thing is that why we need to initialize with value or something as checkbox and other fields are working fine without it , its just the issue with combobox

I simplified your code a little and added a debugger statement the the Check Dirty button's handler to see what's happening. This is the code:
Ext.create("Ext.form.Panel", {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        name: 'combobox',
        displayField: 'Value',
        valueField: 'Key',
        store: {
            data: [{
                Key: 'Item1',
                Value: 'Item1'
            }, {
                Key: 'Item2',
                Value: 'Item2'
            }, ]
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        name: 'checkbox',
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Check Dirty',
        handler: function () {
            var fPanel = this.up();
            fPanel.down('combobox').resetOriginalValue();
            fPanel.down('checkbox').resetOriginalValue();
            debugger;
            alert("Field panel is Dirty :" + fPanel.isDirty());
        }
    }]
});


After running the Fiddle and pressing Check Dirty I added some watch values in the debugger and I was pretty surprised to see this:

So both fields are not dirty but the panel itself is dirty? This sounds weird.
But if I change to toolkit from modern to classic it works as it should! So my guess is that it is a bug in the modern toolkit - or if it is intended behaviour then I don't understand it.
You could implement a simple function to loop all the fields and consider the form to be dirty if any of the fields are dirty.

yup i believe the same that its a bug in the modern toolkit , i have override isDirty method by looping all the field and checking dirty on each field.. Thanks
